# cardinality estimation when the foreign key is limited to a small subset

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, microsoft-dynamics

Recently I have been optimizing the performance of a large scale ERP packet.
One of the performance issues I haven't been able to solve involves bad cardinality estimation for a foreign key which is limited to a very small subset of records from a large table.

Table A holds 3 mil records and has a type field

Table B holds 7 mil records and holds a foreign key FK to Table A

The foreign key will only be filled with primary keys from table A with a certain type, only 36 from the 3 mil records in Table A have this certain type.

B JOIN A ON B.FK = A.PK AND A.TYPE = X AND A.Name = Y

Now using the correct statistics SQL knows table A will only return 1 value

But SQL estimates only 2 records will be returned from table B (my guess is 7 mil / 3 mil) while actually 930 000 records are returned
This results in a slow query plan being used.

The real query is more complex but the cause of the bad query plan is because of this simplified statement.

Our DB does have accurate statistics for the FK (histogram shows EQ_Rows for every distinct value of this FK) and filtering on a fixed FK value does result in accurate estimations.

Is there any way to show SQL that this FK can only hold a small amount of distinct values or in any other way help him with the estimations.

If we had a chance we would split up the table and put these 36 records in a separate table but unfortunately this is how the ERP system works.

Extra info:
We are using SQL 2014. 
The ERP system is Dynamics AX 2012 R3
Using trace flag 9481 does help (not perfect but a lot better) but unfortunately we cannot set trace flags for separate queries with Dynamics AX

Comment: I would try to create a filtered index and put `TYPE = X AND Name = Y` into the filter of an index. Then I would check if optimizer chooses to use such index.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered these kinds of problems before, and have often found that I can dramatically reduce total run time for a stored proc or script by pulling those 'very few relevant rows' from a large table into a small temp table and then joining that temp table into the main query later.  Or using CTE queries to isolate the few needed rows.   A little experimentation should quickly tell you if this has potential in your case.

Comment: Also,  here is a link to a Microsoft page that speaks to this problem.  

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181034%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately we are very limited in the Dynamics system, we can however use a temp table, this might be a good idea to try out.

Comment: One reason why temps/CTEs works so well is that for those isolated selects, there is only one table so it has no decision to make on which table to start with.  It may however have a decision on which index to start with, so be sure you have coded in favor of the index that will serve you best.  Meaning : use WHERE criteria that evaluates most/all of the fields covered by the desired index.  Especially be sure the leading index fields are used.  If you miss a leading index field, that index will be skipped and wont help you at all.  You may need to create an index for this, if you are allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is more information:
We have a grid filled with workitems for the current user.
This is the query: 
Select workitems 
join casedetails on workitem.FK = casedetails.PK
join parties on casedetails.FK = parties.PK
where workitems.user = currentuser
and parties.type = department

now our users are applying a filter on Parties.name (a specific department)
Because of estimations the casedetails are retrieved first while retrieving workitems for the current user first would be much more efficient. Index usage is correct, just the order of the query plan is inefficient

Comment: Can you show the DDL for the tables ( including indexes ) ?   And...is this the complete SQL ?  It does not list the selected field, or a FROM clause.    Lastly, are you free to alter the SQL as needed ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the query plan
Clearly you want it to filter on TYPE early
It is probably doing loop join

```
FROM B 
JOIN A 
  ON B.FK   = A.PK 
 AND A.TYPE = X 
 AND A.Name = Y
```

Try the various [join hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx)

Next would be to create a #temp and join to it
Declare a PK on you temp

Comment: We cannot force hints from the dynamics system.
SQL does filter on type early, problem is when we look at the complete query the result is a low number of records because of other filters applied. But sql start his query plan with table A and B because he estimates only 2 records will return while actually this is 93K records.
If the estimations would be correct the query plan would probably not start with table A and B and start with a more selective filter.